# How to forward request to different web applicaions with same domain but different path correctly on IIS?

Tags: iis, next.js

I have a web server running multiple react web applications with different port, and I want to visit them with same domain but different path.

Like if I visiting localhost/webapp1/index, it redirect to localhost:3000, or visiting localhost/webapp2/index then redirect to lcoalhost:4000.

First of all, I locate my IIS website physical path to the root folder called websites, which contain all the webapps seperate by folder. And the folder name is match with the first layer of the url path, e.g:  webapp1, webapp2, etc.

[image]

Then I added a URL rewrite rules in the folders like below to redirect request to the corresponding web server:

[image]

It did what I want. if I visit localhost/webapp1/index, it going to port 3000, if I visit another url like localhost/webapp2/index, it going to port 4000 and so on.

But I am facing the problem that it can't really request the correct location of files

[image]

[image]

The correct file location should be <my-domain>/webapp1/_next/static/css/455380e8d74e6160.css

Should I add more rules to do some rewrite? How can I fix it on IIS?

Comment: Such 404 errors are caused by a common mistake to use URL Rewrite module with ARR installed, https://halfblood.pro/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59#mistake-3-write-proxy-rules-without-arr-proxy If you want Node.js web apps hosting on IIS, you should use HttpPlatformHandler instead, https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

Comment: Usually  we need to use iisnode and URLRewrite to deploy NextJs on an IIS server in Windows. https://medium.com/@dipneupane/deploying-nextjs-application-on-windows-iis-server-cabdc22bccf8

Comment: @LexLi I do changed my way to launch nodejs with httpPlatformHandler, but how can I seperate my http request by path to different port of web apps?

Comment: 1) First, understand IIS concepts like sites, applications, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis 2) Since you want to host two apps under a single site, create two IIS applications under the same, and use HttpPlatformHandler on each of the applications.